# Job queuing in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an existing rails application. Now I want to implement job queuing in my application for performance enhancement and for the improvement of user experience Now suppose I have a button in some page of my application. Clicking on that particular button does a specific task. Now I want that each time after the button click the corresponding job requests will be queued accordingly in back end and will be processed one after another.

Please tell me how to implement the concept in rails. Or is there any tutorial for this or not.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is something that you could probably google pretty easily. One commonly-used queueing library is [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki) which is easy to set up and has exceptionally good documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sidekiq gem](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is your best option ([here is](http://sidekiq.org/) project's webpage).

Also see the official tutorial on [ActiveJob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Comment: Thnx @Andrey,,,,,I have solved the issue using that gem,Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Abhradip no probs :)